# Keycloak export for big database is taking too long

Tags: java, jboss, keycloak

We are running some tests using **Keycloak 3.4.3** and exporting a database with 10k users. This is the code we use:

```
ExportImportConfig.setAction(ExportImportConfig.ACTION_EXPORT);
ExportImportConfig.setDir(backupFolderPath);
ExportImportConfig.setProvider(ExportImportConfig.PROVIDER_DEFAULT);
ExportImportConfig.setUsersExportStrategy(ExportImportConfig.DEFAULT_USERS_EXPORT_STRATEGY);
ExportImportConfig.setUsersPerFile(500);

ExportImportManager eiManager = new ExportImportManager(keycloakSession);
eiManager.runExport();
```

The time it takes to do a backup is about 1 minute per generated file, no matter how many users we put in that file (we tried with the default of 50 and got up to 500).

Are we missing some config that could help improve that time?

P.S. We also checked the Keycloak JIRA, but the only post we have found is [KEYCLOAK-2413](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/KEYCLOAK-2413) and the fix for it was using "dir" export strategy, which we are already using. It is also a very old question, asked for Keycloak 1.